# Execute a directive after another

Tags: angularjs, directive

I started with angular. I would like a directive runs after another but I do not.

my template, it's show a carousel. each li containe 6 pictures :

```
<section class="page">
<ul class="row menu_image image" rn-carousel="" rn-carousel-indicator="">
    <div carousel-Directive="" file="fichier"></div>
</ul>
</section>
```

rn-carousel make a carousel with li : https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel

the controller of this :

```
function troupesController($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $scope.fichier ="js/data/troupes.json";
}
```

carousel-Directive (shows 6 part of a table in li):

```
app.directive("carouselDirective", ["$compile", "$http", function ($compile, $http) {    
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope:{
        file:'='
    },
    link: function (scope, element,attr) {

        $http.get(scope.file).success(function(data) {

             var dataset = scope.file;//data;
             var html='<li>';
                angular.forEach(dataset,function(item,index){
                     if(index%6==0 && index!==0){
                         html+="</li><li>";
                     } 

                    html+='<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">';        
                    html+=    '<a href="#/troupes"><img src="img-min/'+item.basic_image+'" alt="'+item.name+'" /></a>';
                    html+='</div>';
                });

                html+="</li>";
                element.append($compile(html)(scope));
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

I have see the priority option for directive but it's not the solution. 
I move the ul with the directive 'nr-carousel' directive in my 'carouselDirective' as below :

```
app.directive("carouselDirective", ["$compile", "$http", function ($compile, $http) {    
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope:{
        file:'='
    },
    link: function (scope, element,attr) {

        $http.get(scope.file).success(function(data) {

             var dataset = scope.file;//data;
             var html='<ul class="row menu_image image" rn-carousel="" rn-carousel-indicator=""><li>';
                angular.forEach(dataset,function(item,index){
                     if(index%6==0 && index!==0){
                         html+="</li><li>";
                     } 

                    html+='<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">';        
                    html+=    '<a href="#/troupes"><img src="img-min/'+item.basic_image+'" alt="'+item.name+'" /></a>';
                    html+='</div>';
                });

                html+="</li></ul>";
                element.append($compile(html)(scope));
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

but I have this error :

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$rootScope/inprog?p0=NaNigest
at Error (<anonymous>)
at http://guide-coc.programmation-web.fr/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:6:450
at n (http://guide-coc.programmation-web.fr/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:98:34)
at h.$digest (http://guide-coc.programmation-web.fr/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:101:144)
at x (http://guide-coc.programmation-web.fr/js/libs/angular-carousel/angular-carousel.min.js:8:2555)
at http://guide-coc.programmation-web.fr/js/libs/angular-carousel/angular-carousel.min.js:8:4811
at I (http://guide-coc.programmation-web.fr/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:49:397)
at h (http://guide-coc.programmation-web.fr/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:42:437)
at http://guide-coc.programmation-web.fr/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:42:105
at http://guide-coc.programmation-web.fr/js/app.js:62:44
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the problem with this is, it shows that you have multiple digest try to run at the same time. As you hit the request once digest starts and as it was not able to stop, your code hit the second digest and that's why it's showing digest inprogress.

```
$element.on('click', function() {
        $scope.$apply(doSomeWork); // <<< the $apply call was moved to the callsite that doesn't execute in $apply call already
      });
```

This most probably solves your problem.

Comment: I have test ad $scope.$apply to my directive and it's don't work, i have the same error.

        link: function (scope, element,attr) {
         scope.$apply(function () {
          ...
               
       element.append($compile(html)(scope));
              
  });
        });